# Django-filter: count data

Tags: python, django, django-filter

Does anybody knows how can I use count based on selected value using `django_filters`

#### Error

```
'UserFilter' object has no attribute 'count'
```

My Reference [link](https://tutorial101.blogspot.com/2020/06/django-how-to-filter-querysets.html)

#### views.py

```py
  def search(request):
      user_list = Person.objects.all()
      user_filter = UserFilter(request.GET, queryset=user_list)
      count = user_filter.count() #this will return an error
      print(count)
      return render(request, 'user_list.html', {'filter': user_filter})
```

#### filters.py

```py
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from .models import Person
    import django_filters
     
    class UserFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
        class Meta:
            model = Person
            fields = ['category', 'firstname', 'lastname' ]
```

#### user_list.html

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %} 
    {% block content %}
      <form method="get">
        {{filter.form.as_p}}
          <button type="submit" >Search</button>
      </form>
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th> Lastname</th>
            <th>Caegory</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for user in filter.qs %}
            <tr>
              <td>{{ user.firstname }}</td>
              <td>{{ user.lastname }}</td>
              <td>{{ user.category }}</td>
            </tr>
          {% empty %}
            <tr>
              <td colspan="5">No data</td>
            </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    {% endblock %}
```

I want to count all the list base from data I filtered

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want the count of the resulting queryset, which you can get from the filter's `qs` property (as you do in your template!).

Change

```
count = user_filter.count()
```

to

```
count = user_filter.qs.count()
```

Comment: thanks it works ,by the way what is meaning of qs and what is the function of this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can work with the `.qs` attribute:

```
def search(request):
  user_list = Person.objects.all()
  user_filter = UserFilter(request.GET, queryset=user_list)
  count = user_filter.qs.count()
  return render(request, 'user_list.html', {'filter': user_filter})
```

[**`.qs`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/blob/2.4.0/django_filters/filterset.py#L237-L245) is a property that generates a `QuerySet` by *filtering* the original queryset by values in the fields of the `FilterSet`.

Comment: thanks it works ,by the way what is meaning of qs and what is the function of this ?

Comment: @Dason_Dy: `.qs` is a property: https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/blob/master/django_filters/filterset.py#L237 it generates a new queryset that is filtered by the fields.

Comment: By the way Im wondering  if this would work?  `ordered = sorted(bene.qs, key=operator.attrgetter('barangay'))`  putting

Comment: @Jason_Dy: please *don't*. This sorts at the Django/Python layer. It is better to sort at the database layer, so `user_list = Person.objects.order_by('barangay')`.